# Sort files according to their filetype

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh

After an HD problem and some work, I have a bunch of files with names like "f1234", "f1235", etc.

My goal is to sort this files according to their filetype. For example, I want to move all the PDF files in the "pdfs" directory.

For one file, I can do : "file f1234", and if it's a PDF, I can "mv f1234 pdfs/". But I have thousands of file... Can you help me with a bash or zsh command for sort all the PDF in one pass ? Thanks

Comment: `for f in f* ; do case $(file "$f") in PDF ) echo /bin/mv "$f" /path/to/pdf/dir/"$f".pdf ;; * ) echo "not a PDF $f" 1>&2 ;; esac ; done`. Examine the output carefully, and if it looks OK, then remove the `echo` on the PDF case. You'll have to change `in PDF` to match the real output of `file f1234` when it is a PDF. (Dbl-quote the match string if there are any spaces). Good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hard part here is reliably turning the output of `file` into a directory name. I think probably the best candidate for that is the mime-type of the file rather than the human readable output of `file`. I'd use something like:

```
mkdir sorted
for f in f*
do
  d=$(file -b --mime-type "$f" | tr / -)
  mkdir -p "sorted/$d"
  mv "$f" "sorted/$d/"
done
```

Obviously I'd test that out a bit before running it on your files, but something pretty close to that should work.

Comment: `file -bi "$f" | cut -d';' -f1 | tr / -` can be shortened to `file -b --mime-type "$f" | tr / -`.

Comment: Ahh, that is better! I'll change the answer to reflect that.